# Android Hilt ViewModel Injecting Context Depending Classes

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I have a question about architecture. I know that View Model should not know anything about activity and context. But what if I have to use inside it Shared Preferences or Account Manager? If I create a wrapper class and Inject it into View Model by contructor will it be right from android architectural princicipals?

Thank you in advance for any help
Paweł

Comment: `Shared Preferences` only required a Context this can be an Application Context . So you create a Repo for Shared Preferences and inject the context there via HILT then just use the Repo inside `ViewModel` .

Comment: So the same can be done with AccountManager and it will be right from architectural point, correct me if I’m wrong...